# Use of 'since' and 'ever since'

Tags: difference, since

Is there any difference between 'ever since' and 'since' when used in a sentence? Are they same and interchangeable to use? Please explain with examples.

Answer (score 9):

The preposition *since* is used to refer back to a previous point in time:

> It’s been years since I rode a bike.
>
> Since joining the company, I've  been promoted twice.

Since also has meanings with no reference to time:

> Since you ask, I'll say yes.
>
> Since he didn't study, he didn't pass the exam.

*Ever since* is used when you want to emphasize that something has been true from "from that time to this".The "ever" can suggest a continous thing and suggest against the possibily that something has happened only intermittently since:

> Ever since we met, we have been been good friends.
>
> His grandmother doesn’t go for walks on her own ever since she fell at
>   the bus stop.
>
> My father has not smiled ever since my mother died.

To see the difference, here are two more examlpes:

> My back has been aching since I fell off the ladder.
>
> Ever since I fell off the ladder, my back aches.

To make a long story short,"ever" is just an intensifier. There's no principal difference in meaning when you add it or remove it.

Comment: Can we use 'since' in the place of 'ever since' without changing the meaning of sentence ?

Comment: Whichever of the two you use, the meaning of the sentence won't change.

Comment: You mean they are intercheable ?

Comment: Not always. To make it clearer, I added a couple of examples.

Comment: Oh i got it, ever since imphasizes the result of event, and means 'has been continued up to now'. BUT since only refers to the point of event. AM i right ?

Comment: It sooner emphasizes the long lasting or permanent effect

Comment: "Ever since" is less ambiguous. It can only have the continuously-after meaning. Without "ever", "since" can have the continuously-after meaning, the point-subsequent-to meaning, or the causal meaning (like "because").

Answer (score 1):

" .. that ever since he had shown up on Friday with a Philippine T’nalak duffel bag slung over one arm and a cold case of Old Latrobe under the other .. " from my own writing would be yet another example as it specifies that "ever since he had shown up on 'Friday'" something happened or became true, thereby resolving any ambiguity in timing of events. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158384/since-vs-ever-since

.

Answer (score 0):

The word *since* is a subordinating conjunction if it introduces a clause as in:

You must serve detention after school today since you were tardy.
Since you were tardy, you must serve detention after school today.

Notice that in the second example sentence there is a comma after the subordinate clause.

Answer (score -1):

I believe using "*ever since*" indicates from one point in time / occasion / circumstance till another point in time. The simple use of *since* can mean the aforementioned or "as a result or consequence of" this or that.